# System restore eating up hard drive space?

Tags: hard-drive, system-restore, windows-xp

I had maximum allotted system restore space for a drive set to about `4 GB` But how could I gained `25 GB` of free space on that same drive on turning system restore off ?

**Edit:**

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRestore

[image]

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRestore\Cfg

[image]

Comment: Right after clearing the system restore by cycling it Off and then back On, Be sure to create a manual restore point

Comment: Nice utility here to manage restore points...http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/downloads-windows/31116-download-qrm-plus-manager-manage-windows-system-restore-points.html

Comment: How large space is the hard disk all-in-all ?

Comment: @harrymc: `160 GB`, On a `40 GB` partition it freed up about `25 GB` which was for windows directory.

Comment: not an ans, but you may be interested, ERUNT just backups the registry. is a good program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not always automatically delete everything in the restore directory other than the 4 GB you set it to. You also could have had some malware in the restore directory. Windows will delete most stuff from the restore directory when you turn it off, so it can delete some malware files (but not always).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on XP, it looks like Microsoft simply ignores your setting.

From [The Registry Keys and Values for the System Restore Utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295659) for XP :

> **DiskPercent**
>
> This value relates to the percentage
>   of disk space that System Restore uses
>   for its data store. The default value
>   is 12 percent. **The data store size
>   is always calculated as "max(12
>   percent, DSMax)," regardless of the
>   size of the hard disk.**
>
> **DSMax**
>
> This value specifies the maximum size
>   for the System Restore data store. The
>   default size of the data store is 400
>   MB. **The data store size is always
>   calculated as "max(12 percent,
>   DSMax)," regardless of the size of the
>   hard disk.**

However, the 25 GB you freed on a 40 GB disk is 62,5% rather than 12%. This means that the whole algorithm is non-functional, so there are actually no real limits. One hopes that this was corrected in later versions of Windows. However, such a malfunction can easily pass unnoticed, since Windows is supposed to automatically liberate this space if required.